# Get DbContext in ASP.NET outside of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET Core Application.
My Controller invoke a SessionService. (responsible for SignalR HubService and DbService). Inside this SessionService i call a **ScriptHandler**, which will live until it completed its Script and will even live through the controller call up. Here is some example code:

```
public Class SessionService
{
 public SessionService(DbContext _dbcontext, IHubContext<MyHub> _hub)
 public async task buttonClicked()
 {
 ScriptHandler sh = new ScriptHandler()
 sh.RunScript();
 }
}
```

Inside this SessionService i start a ScriptHandler Task:

```
public class ScriptHandler
{
 public async Task RunScript(string scriptContents)
  using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
   {
    ps.AddScript(scriptContents);
    var pipelineObjects = await ps.InvokeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    foreach (var item in pipelineObjects)
     {
      OUTPUT in database but i'm missing the DbContext
     }
   }
}
```

Do you have any idea how i get the DbContext, because its not surviving when i pass it through my SessionService class.

Comment: Is your controller action returning before the script completes?

Comment: Yes. That's the point. My idea Was to start a Script with a Button. Meanwhile the Browser could be closed. And the ScriptHandler will write the final Script output in a database. So next time i visit the site in Browser i See the database output. Any idea if this is even possible in asp.Net core?

Comment: There's a couple problems with this. First, a DI-injected `DbContext` is only available for the lifetime of the request. So you'd need a different `DbContext` for the request-extrinsic  code. The second problem is that ASP.NET isn't really designed for request-extrinsic code at all. It's possible to get it working, but rather tricky. Instead, I'd recommend adding a reliable queue and a separate background process that reads requests from that queue and handles them.